# A legal scientific/techno hobby constitution to a need in killing

Tags: science-based, technology, psychology

The narrative is set in present or very near future. Jane's *(the character's)* past is an abysmal nightmare, a bottomless pit with no education, life experience — nothing but darkness. Despite being a mature girl, she basically had to start the life again. She somewhat managed to climb in math and programming through self-education, aiming for scientific career, but she lags behind for about a decade in socializing herself.

Her social attempts are bound to fail due to excessively abstract thinking and weak communication capabilities, and she discovers the reason — schizotypal disorder.

So, sometimes the jealousy to others' lives, the loneliness, the past, the peoples' oddness, and their unpredictable *(due to her abstract mindset)* behavior strikes her down; she blackouts in waves of pain and hatred. She would love becoming a serial killer, a nice way to satisfy herself. But she've got a dream in science, and she can't take the risk of going to a jail. So she has to satisfy the hatred with more-or-less legal hobby.

**The question**: what legal and bound to technology/science hobby would you imagine for an overly logical person to constitute the need in killing? So far I've only come up with α) she goes develop a videogame, from a maniac to maniacs *(I'm not sure I could present this one to readers in a non-boring way, unless there's some gem I didn't see)*, or β) she develops weapons *(this one is off, because it's hardly possible beyond some job)*.

Comment: She moves in direction of conquering the world, by inventions, she have a plan to do so.

Comment: Internet trolling, serial killing in massively multiplayer real time video games where that is not part of the game, hunting, joining a highly structured cult or militia, noir novel writing, vigilante destruction of property or graffiti tagging, BSDM as a dominant, cyber stalking, torturing animals (perhaps those of people she envies), the list goes on as the meaning to her matters more than the objective meaning.

Comment: I think this question is the definition of opinion based. As such, I'm voting to close. Find out more about our scope [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors?cb=1)

Comment: @ohwilleke writing very complex and creative viruses for Windows! What a nice idea! Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, does SHE need to be killed, or does she need a legal way to get away with murder?

Comment: @ohwilleke I think you could post your comment as an answer, in particular the part that meaning to her matters more than objective meaning.

Comment: @Tezra she hates people, her feelings varies from neutral to a hatredy. She actually would want to entertain herself with killing, but here comes the danger of jail. She's not so much afraid of getting killed as to lose her freedom. So she have to have a *(semi)* legal hobby-constitution to killing, something that makes other peoples suffer or die, but without a danger for her to fall into a jail.

Answer (score 2):

In a comical fashion, I present [The funniest joke ever told](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJxePohdHQAhXD7CYKHSTXD7EQtwIIJzAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dienp4J3pW7U&usg=AFQjCNFoHviG19ZPhfzR9xdpKVE5Fw9zKA&bvm=bv.139782543,d.eWE) by Monty Python's Flying Circus. Although instead of jokes, make it poems, and instead of laughing to death, the poems make anyone who reads them suicidal.

As long as she is not writing about direct attacks on people (to harass, or make fearful of their lives), there is nothing wrong with writing poems.

I'm going to add, poems are an informal form of expression, they do not HAVE to be in any perticular format or rhyme. While this is technically an 'art', psychology is a science... but the 'she fails at everything' desciption of her personality, she is more likely to achive this through astonomical failure rather than actually applying psychology to drive people mad/suicidal.

Comment: On the contrary, if these poems can be proven to be the primary cause of suicide, then I'd think there'd be a risk of being convicted for manslaughter or endangerment.

Comment: @FirstLastname, That would basically be the same as blaming a blacksmith because someone used one the daggers he made to kill someone. By law, she is innocent until proven that she deliberately wanted to kill people. (This is why some lawsuits fail. The defendant can just say 'I didn't know' and get away with things like false advertising)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there in the question:

> But she've got a dream in science, and she can't take the risk of
>   going to a jail.

[is not that uncommon to think or fantasize to kill](http://psychcentral.com/ask-the-therapist/2015/03/07/why-do-i-fantasize-about-killing-people/) but then again, a sane, logical side of us will weighed that it would be bad to us and to our victim therefore we do other things. And she already got a dream to pursue so despite her dark past, and awkwardness, so she just can get on with her life.

If her dreams are not related to figure out how to killing people while cheating 
the laws, and her urge to blood are that bad she may choose a hardcore bdsm or vampiric cult that shed blood as her hobbies.

Comment: So, can she get on with her life, or have she to join a cult? :Ь Anyways, a dream is just a point for life to go, it can't be used for everyday satisfaction. And she can't get on with her life, because she can't even join the society. The ways she and everyone thinks are diverges, leading to awkward, or simply bad, situations.